# Update NSArrayController correctly

Tags: swift3, key-value-observing

I'm trying to populate NSTableView using NSArrayController, however can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private let _spadList: SpadList

    var spadList : SpadList {
        get { return _spadList }
    }

    override init() {
        _spadList = SpadList()
        super.init()
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        createInitialData()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func createInitialData() {

        _spadList.chain = "CHAIN"
        _spadList.service = "Service"
        _spadList.dateString = "2016-12-12"

        let firstEquity = Equity()
        let anotherEquity = Equity()

        firstEquity.name = "Apple"
        firstEquity.tradePrice = 12.3

        anotherEquity.name = "ORACLE"
        anotherEquity.tradePrice = 45.7

        _spadList.addEquity(equity: firstEquity)
        _spadList.addEquity(equity: anotherEquity)


    }
 }
```

And this is ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    func equities() -> [Equity]{
        return appDelegate.spadList.equities
    }
}
```

Content Array of the NSArrayController is bound to: ViewController.equities

The issue is that my manually created data are not populating itself into my tableView. If I move createInitialData() to ViewController class, they are correctly displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use a function as data source, use a stored property and add the `dynamic` attribute. And in Swift declaring read only properties by backing private variables is ridiculous. Just use a constant (`let`): `private let spadList = SpadList()` does exactly the same as the entire code above `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Comment: Hm, not sure I got it. I changed code to:    `dynamic var equities: [Equity]{
        return appDelegate.spadList.equities
    }` but it didn't help. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: Declare `equities` as an empty array and assign the array from AppDelegate in `viewDidLoad`. But why don't you move the entire code related to the table view to the view controller? Your design seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: yeah I know. But I will update contents from network code and it makes more sense to store data in AppDelegate to me. However I still can't get it to work. Would you mind to show me the correct code?

Comment: Declare the property `dynamic var equities = [Equity]()` - move the code in `viewWillAppear()` `equities = appDelegate.spadList.equities`. `viewWillAppear` is more appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. It looks like myArrayController is not notified about changes in `appDelegate.spadList.equities` array :( It seems like `dynamic` is not enough here

Comment: Right, if changes are made in AppDelegate the array in the view controller is not updated. The `dynamic` keyword affects only the KVO relationship via Cocoa Bindings. You have to add KVO programmatically or bind the array controller to the key path in AppDelegate.